# http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll() doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm trying to give anonymous access to some urls here is the code :

```
 @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/","/boutique**","/proprietaires**","/produits**").permitAll()
            .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable();
        }
```

But it still gives "401" error.

Can anyone show me what i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

It must : `antMatchers("/","/boutique/**","/proprietaires/**","/produits/**"`. You missing `/`